# Data retrieval failure from Oracle to Spark-sql with no Error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

All my efforts to retrieve data from Oracle(LDAP) using spark-sql failed. I am using

```
sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT field1 from Table WHERE CREATED_TimeStamp BETWEEN 'timestamp1' AND 'timestamp2")
```

and **field1** is only CLOB type on this oracle table.

It can't print or save the result data and the process stuck right there without error for long time. 
However result.count() gives me correct number of rows

I can however print data successfully with something like "SELECT field1 from Table LIMIT 5".
I can retrieve any other field beside **field1** using **BETWEEN** condition , so query should be fine.

I have tried **before** and **after** timestamp methods on dataset , it didnt work either.

Problem looks weird , I can either print field1 data or use **Between** condition, not both at a time . I am using spark 2 and scala 2.11.5. What could be possible issue ?

Comment: LOB types have specific accessors on Oracle side (technically speaking, the column just contains a pointer to a distinct storage segment, you have to read/write data with buffers etc.) so I am not surprised that the JDBC driver cannot emulate 100 % of what you would get on a plain VARCHAR2.

Comment: Did you *persist* the DataFrame inside Spark memory (where the CLOB should be converted to StringType once and for all) or do you access Oracle on each query again and again (with different Spark optimizer choices)?

Comment: Yes it is persisted ,but field with CLOB type is not converted to string explicitly. I can see printSchema method returns string automatically for that field.  I can easily retrieve same field when date conditions(between) are removed from the query, Do you still think JDBC driver is not emulating complete value ?

Comment: Could be a code page issue i.e. imported String not in UTF-8. Or it could be anything...